# kubernetes RBAC DENY not preventing access

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running a gke 1.8.4 cluster, and seeing an issue with requests to access resources being permitted, even though RBAC is denying them

from logs/kube-apiserver.log (I've replaced my username and the username I'm impersonating, in <*italics*>):

> I1218 13:30:38.644205       5 httplog.go:64] &{<*my_user*>  [system:authenticated] map[]} is acting as &{<*other_user*>  [system:authenticated] map[]}
>   I1218 13:30:38.644297       5 rbac.go:116] RBAC DENY: user "<*other_user*>" groups ["system:authenticated"] cannot "list" resource "secrets" in namespace "prod"
>   I1218 13:30:38.676079       5 wrap.go:42] GET /api/v1/namespaces/prod/secrets: (32.043196ms) 200 [[kubectl/v1.8.4 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/9befc2b]

Why is the api proceeding to the GET after the RBAC DENY (and ultimately returning the secrets in response to my kubectl cmd)?

fwiw my kubectl cmd is: `kubectl get secrets --namespace prod --as <other_user>`

I suspect there's another authorizer that's allowing it, though I've done everything I know of to ensure there isn't (ABAC should be disabled, as I'm on 1.8, the google cloud console shows it as being disabled, and I'm seeing "legacyAbac: {}" in the response from *gcloud beta container clusters describe*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GKE enables both the RBAC authorizer and a webhook authorizer that consults GKE IAM. Does the specified username have permissions via GKE?

Comment: Ah, I totally should have checked that! Even after checking the multitude of online sources, I still wasn't aware that the webhook authorizer was enabled by default, but it does make a load of sense now

I'll get tidying up our GKE IAM. Many thanks Jordan!